# Updating a mysql table from an array (HTML form input)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update one row (= ID) of a mysql table from multiple form fields (text fields and text areas). The table looks like this:

ID | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 ... | Col 50

Everything works fine, if I use $_Post[] variables like this

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Name2 = $_POST['Name2'];  
$sql= "UPDATE Bilder SET Name = '$Name', Name2 = '$Name2' WHERE id = '$ID'"; 


<form id="InsertData" action="insert-dataset.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="'.$row->id.'" /> 
  <input type="text" name="Name" value="'.$row->Name.'" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="Name2" value="'.$row->Name.'" /><br />  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Daten eintragen" class="sendbutton" /> 
</form>
```

Since I have hundreds of fields I would rather use an array like so:

```
<input type="text" name="Name[]" value="'.$row->Name.'" />
```

I found working examples for updating all cells of one column. But I have to update all colums for one ID.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is the final result:

```
$col_result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM Bilder");
$row_result = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM Bilder WHERE id = %s", $ID));
if(!$col_result) {
    echo 'Konnte Anfrage nicht ausführen: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if ( !empty($_POST) ) { 
    $aDataSet = array(); 
    while( list( $field, $value ) = each( $_POST )) { 
    $aDataSet[] = $field . "='" . $value . "'";
    } 
$update_sql = "UPDATE Bilder SET " . implode( ',', $aDataSet ); 
$update_sql .= sprintf("WHERE id = '$ID'");
$result = mysql_query($update_sql, $connection); 
if(!$result)  
 {  
 die('');  
 }  
 echo '';  
}   
mysql_close($connection)
?>
```

The update query will only include colums that have corresponding input field (input name = column name). Since I have hundreds of input fields, I can spread them over multiple pages using the same code for the update query.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like that:

```
$str = '';
$id = 0;
foreach($_POST['Name'] as $value)
{
    $id ++;
    $str .= ($str == '' ? '' : ', ').'Name'.$id.' = \''.addslashes($value).'\'';
}
$sql= "UPDATE Bilder SET ".$str." WHERE id = '$ID'";
```

Note: on this example, your sql fields are Name1, Name2, Name3...

Note2: you should always at least use an addslashes method when pasting a variable inside a sql query, to protect yourself from hackers.

Comment: You're awewome! Works like a charm. Thank you so much! The only downside is that the column names have to be numbered consecutively. It would be perfect, if I could use, say, Peter, Paul, Mary instead of Name_1, Name_2, Name_3. For this I probably would have to use COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION which is considered bad practice. The background is: The data are imported from Excel spreadsheets. In the spreadsheet there must not be anything else but the table name (the Excel table), the column name (row 1) and the values (row 2). Would be easier for the user to have meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple ideas.

- Name your fields something useful. Naming them garbage like Name1, Name2 etc is going to bite you on the ass later down the line. Also be nice to the next guy thats going to have to look at this.
- If you have a bunch of Meaningful or Unmeaningful fieldnames and don't want to manually type them all out in your code, maybe use the SQL DESCRIBE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) or SHOW COLUMNS command (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php)

Note: untested

```
<?php
// Get all of the field names
$col_result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM Bilder");

// make sure we could get the colnames from mysql
if(!$col_result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

// Handle a POST
if(!empty($_POST)){
    // start preparing the update statement
    $update_sql = "UPDATE Bilder SET ";
    if(mysql_num_rows($col_result) > 0) {
        // make a key = value statement for each column in the table
        while($colrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($col_result)) {
            // prepare the key = value statement
            $update_sql .= sprintf(" %s = %s, ", $colrow["Field"], mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$colrow["Field"]]));
        }
    }
    // BTW this is going to have a extra "," in it use substr to clear it
    $update_sql = substr_replace($update_sql ,"", -2);

    // finish off by limiting this statement to only one row
    $update_sql .= sprintf(" WHERE id = %s", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]));

    // ACTUALLY RUN THIS STATEMENT
}

if(!$row_result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

// prepare the sql to fetch the current row we are working on
    $row_result = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM Bilder WHERE id = %s", $id));

```
// Get the row item that you are currently working on
$row = mysql_fetch_row($row_result);

// output all the formfields for the above row
if(mysql_num_rows($col_result) > 0) {
    // Go through all of the columns and output the colname from $colrow and the value from $row
    while ($colrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($col_result)) {
        // The HTML (don't be daunted by that variable-variable http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)
        echo '<input type="text" name="' . $colrow["Field"] . '" value="' . $row->{$colrow["Field"]} . '" /><br />';
    }
}
?>
```

- lastly, you may be better served by an EAV style of DB where the number of fields for a row is variable. (a fair example with php and mysql: http://www.iwilldomybest.com/2008/08/php-mysql-tip-3/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I changed some minor details,and I'm almost there. I have just the extra ',' to clear. I tried substr and rtrim in different ways, but nothing did the trick. I'm a beginner, sorry to bother you with dumb questions, but how exactly do I have to apply substr?

Comment: this line here: `$update_sql = substr_replace($update_sql ,"", -2);` I added it to my answer as well.

Comment: also you need to still run the sql generated in that block after the `// ACTUALLY RUN THIS STATEMENT` comment.

Comment: Hi Franics, thaanks again. I tried exactly that. Was probably a typo or something. I appreciate your help very much. It helped me a lot to better understand the subject. BTW, I posted my solution with preg_replace before I read your edit.

Comment: I still have a problem with blank fields. It is important that empty $_POST variables are ignored. I tried to expand the if conditon, but it didn't work with `if(strlen($_POST) !== 0` or `if(!empty($_POST) && strlen($_POST) !== 0`. The inputs are on multiple pages. Prepopulating the input fields would therefore not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used preg_replace. This is probably not best practices. The code looks like this and works just fine:

```
// Handle a POST
if(!empty($_POST)){
    // start preparing the update statement
    $update_sql = "UPDATE Bilder SET ";
    if(mysql_num_rows($col_result) > 0) {
        // make a key = value statement for each column in the table
        while($colrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($col_result)) {
            // prepare the key = value statement
        $update_sql .= sprintf("%s = '%s',", $colrow["Field"], mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$colrow["Field"]]));
        }

    }
// BTW this is going to have a extra "," in it use substr to clear it

// finish off by limiting this statement to only one row
$update_sql .= sprintf("WHERE id = '$ID'");
$update_sql = preg_replace("/,WHERE/", "WHERE", $update_sql);
```

There are, of course, security issues. I will fix that. However, this is not that important, since this application is for personal use only. It is not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this kind of thing so I Don't know how safe or effiecnt this is, but it does work.

```
if ($_POST['Submit']=="Update"){
unset($_POST['Submit']);
$refid=$_POST['refid'];
unset($_POST['refid']);
$update=$_POST;
// Update DB with array
foreach ($update as $col => $val) {
        $colsvals=$col."='".$val."'";
            $mysql = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE $tbl SET $colsvals WHERE id='$refid'")
            or die('Database Connection Error ('.mysqli_errno($db).') '.mysqli_error($db). " on query: UPDATE $tbl SET $colsvals WHERE id='$refid'");
        }
}
```

I start by cleaning out things I don't want to Updated.
Then I really had to take a sec to make sure I have the double/single quotes, equals, and dots right in the colsvals statment.
But for me The Magic came from realizing I could let the Foreach loop run a new query each time it etterates through the update array.